# Associate specific configuration of configurable product to product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am trying to create a section of our product view page which will contain a "looks good with.."-part.

Most of the products are configurable in color and size.
If the current product would look good with another product of a certain color.. How would one go about making that relation?

Ideally the customers would click the related item and be shown another configurable product with the color preselected.

We are using Magento CE 1.9.0.1

Comment: are you talking about " http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-selling " ?

Comment: It is cross-selling, but I am more interested in the technical aspect of it.
Is it possible to specify a specific configuration of a configurable product as a possible cross-sell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a custom attribute in the admin such that you can select various cross-sells for each product.  Have these cross sells be simple products (in your case they would be the children of configurable products).  Get these attributes from the product (we use an array containing cross-sell product IDs) and display them on the page however you see fit.

so heres sort of what we do:

we have a .phtml called 'crosssell.phtml' that is loaded wherever on the product page it looks something like this:

```
<?php
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$crossSell = $product->getCrossSellProducts();
$foreach($crossSell as $cxSell){
    $crossSellId=$cxSell->getEntityId();
    $crossSellProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($crossSellId);
    ...display...
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you half an answer.
You can autoselect the configurable product options by adding a hash in the url.
take this url for example:  http://demo.magentocommerce.com/men/shirts/plaid-cotton-shirt-482.html#92=17&180=77
If you click on it you will see that the color and size are already selected.
It all happens because of `#92=17&180=77` from the url.
These value are actually `attribute1_id=attribute1_value&attribtue2_id=attribute2_value`

Now all you need to do is to change the cross-sells links contain the options selected for the main product.